# Why do I see such broken package names, how do I fix it?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, pypi

There are some packages with '-' and '.' in front
and some with only '-' with the name being partly moved to version number.
I don't know how it has happened.
Here is how it looks:

```
$pip list


Package                                Version    
-------------------------------------- -----------
-                                      lenium     
-.lenium                               3.0.2      
-elenium                               3.0.2      
-lenium                                3.0.2      
selenium                               3.141.0
```

`$pip uninstall -.lenium`

or

`$pip uninstall "-.lenium"`

is not working.

Comment: What OS are you on?

Comment: macos (high sierra)

Answer (score 1):

I deleted the package folders as an work around

$`rm -rf ~/.pyenv/versions/3.6.0/lib/python3.6/site-packages/"-.lenium"`

Looking for a better solution or atleast some insight how they might have come in the first place